# How to draw on top on layout when calling camera

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, frame, geometry

I have tried to draw shape on layout that use for camera application. I can draw a rectangle and circle, but i need only frame. It provide me a rectangle that filled, not only frame. I have a picture to show you below. and here is a code of layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.91" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cam_preview"
        android:layout_width="1120dp"
        android:layout_height="840dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="525dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:background="@drawable/square" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="840dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:background="@drawable/circle2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="840dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="800dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonnext" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_camera"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/buttoncamera" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonback" />

</LinearLayout>
```

circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval" >
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ffff0000"/>
</shape>
```

square.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#ffff0000"/>
</shape>
```

note that my layout is fit for 10.1 in Tablet.

[image]

Comment: so whats your problem actually?

Comment: i need to draw only frame of shape, not all solid shape.

Comment: so define it to be "framed"

Comment: can i ask you something, where do i define it.

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 0):

use transparency of colors. For Square.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topRightRadius="1dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1sp"
    android:color="#ffff0000" />
```

solid android:color to fill the color inside the rectangle and it would turn to transparent while stroke android:color would be the lines that is red.